# How to find $abc$ if one is given the values of $a + b + c,$ $a^2 +b^2+c^2, \ a^3+b^3+c^3$ and $ac+bc+ab,$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I am given the values of $a + b + c,$ $a^2 +b^2+c^2, \ a^3+b^3+c^3$ and $ac+bc+ab,$  how do I find value of $abc \ ?$

I expanded  $(a+b+c)^3$ to get  $a^3+b^3+c^3 + 3(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b) +6abc $ but how do I manipulate $3(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b)$ to obtain a fixed value from it?

Appreciate all advice, thank you.

Comment: Note that the information is redundant since $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)$ so before jumping to the conclusion that you have a solution it is worth checking that your initial values are consistent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca).
$$

Comment: 17 secs earlier! and totally same! Oh great...

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

Answer (score 2):

The systematic way for this type of problem would be to use *Newton' identities*, which link *Newton's sums:* 
$$p_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k$$ 
and the *elementary symmetric functions:*
$$\sigma_k(x_1,\dots,x_n)= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n}x_{i_1}\dotsm\, x_{i_n}$$
For $n=3, k=3$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}3abc&=3\sigma_3=\sigma_2p_1-\sigma_1p2+p_3\\
&=(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)-(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a^3+b^3+c^3),
\end{align*}
which of course is the same as the factorisation given above.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? This seems really interesting...

Comment: @goblin One can ask about the symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables, that is, polynomials with $n$ arguments whose values do not depend on the order of the arguments. There are at least two natural bases for these, namely, the Newton sums $p_k$ and the elementary symmetric functions $\sigma_k$. Newton's Identities give (nonlinear) formulas that express one in terms of the other, and this is useful here, because, restarted, the problem asks how to write (for $n = 3$) $\sigma_3$ in terms of $p_1 = \sigma_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, and $\sigma_2$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: @Travis, thanks.

Comment: @goblin You're welcome.